# Multithreading or how to avoid blocking in a Python-application

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm developing a Python-application that "talks" to the user, and performs tasks based on what the user says(e.g. User:"Do I have any new facebook-messages?", answer:"Yes, you have 2 new messages. Would you like to see them?"). Functionality like integration with facebook or twitter is provided by plugins. Based on predefined parsing rules, my application calls the plugin with the parsed arguments, and uses it's response. The application needs to be able to answer multiple query's from different users at the same time(or practically the same time).

Currently, I need to call a function, "Respond", with the user input as argument. This has some disadvantages, however:

i)The application can only "speak when it is spoken to". It can't decide to query facebook for new messages, and tell the user whether it does, without being told to do that.

ii)Having a conversation with multiple users at a time is very hard, because the application can only do one thing at a time: if Alice asks the application to check her Facebook for new messages, Bob can't communicate with the application.

iii)I can't develop(and use) plugins that take a lot of time to complete, e.g. download a movie, because the application isn't able to do anything whilesame the previous task isn't completed.

Multithreading seems like the obvious way to go, here, but I'm worried that creating and using 500 threads at a time dramatically impacts performance, so using one thread per query(a query is a statement from the user) doesn' seem like the right option.

What would be the right way to do this? I've read a bit about Twisted, and the "reactor" approach seems quite elegant. However, I'm not sure how to implement something like that in my application.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? 3.3 would be quite ideal for this one.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Out of interest, what is it about 3.3 that makes it particularly well suited for this?

Comment: @JonasWielick: I'm currently using 2.7, but I'm willing to switch to 3.3 if that version would be more appropriate.

Comment: Python 3.3 features [PEP-380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), which I think is really helpful when implementing reactor-like environments. You'd implement the tasks as coroutines. With some frame work you can then make all the functions yield on I/O and implement some light-weight cooperative multitasking.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: I'm not quite sure how to use generators for this. Could you explain what you have in mind?

Comment: Well, in fact I came to PEP-380 from a framework which did pretty much what I'm suggesting now (so it's not my idea). It's been some time since I read about it and I'm unable to find it again. It was using generators and special yielded values to schedule tasks and allow tasks to hand over control during I/O. It's been basically a specialized threading-implementation, using generators as coroutines. Task A yields read1000bytesfromsocket and Task B could proceed until it yields, then the scheduler checks if Task A can run again, if so, Task A completes, having the bytes read returned from yield

Comment: To clarify, you could do the same without ``yield from``. However, recursion (or refactoring into subroutines in general) becomes a beast then, as a simple ``for item in subroutine(): yield item`` is not totally sufficient (read PEP-380 for more info on that). So it's much more convenient with Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't really understand what sort of application its going to be, but i tried to anwser your questions

1. create a thread that query's, and then sleeps for a while
2. create a thread for each user, and close it when the user is gone
3. create a thread that download's and stops

after all, there ain't going to be 500 threads.

Comment: I was actually looking for a more elegant solution. If 500 clients connect to the server, it's going to be running 500 threads at the same time anyway. I don't know if that's bad, but it does sound bad.

Comment: Well, i don't think 500 threads would hurt a strong PC (maybe it does, Kernel runs with 163 threads). But i have no experience with Twisted or async

Comment: So... parsing each query in a seperate thread is no problem? It seems like a really ugly solution, but perhaps there's no valid reason for me thinking that. I'll try it, and report back my findings.